# mod_wsgi and pylons: setting the working environment

Tags: python, pylons, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to setup Pylons (1.0) with Apache mod_wsgi.  Everything works fine with mod_wsgi and I can run a simple python wsgi app just fine.

I've got the [quickwiki example from the Pylons site](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/tutorials/quickwiki_tutorial/) working when running it with paster, but obviously I would never deploy in such a manner - so I'm trying to get the Quickwiki example working with mod_wsgi. When I use paster to run the site, I have to `source ./pylons/bin/activate` and I feel like this is the "step" that is missing when trying to get it working with mod_wsgi.  The `./pylons/bin/activate` script is the one that was in the source when downloading pylons.

When using it with mod_wsgi, I get:

> ImportError: No module named
>   paste.deploy

I've looked at [this site](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithPylons) but just appending the path of the pylons app doesn't do it.

I've also looked at [this site](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/mod_wsgi+and+workingenv.py), but it didn't seem to do anything significant (and 
didn't solve the issue) when issuing:

```
import activate_workingenv
activate_workingenv.activate_workingenv(WORKING_ENV)
```

Looking at the `sys.path` after issuing  `source ./pylons/bin/activate` shows like a dozen things added to the path, including the paster stuff and all my requirements.  I'd rather not hardcode all those  in the script - what am I missing here?

I'm new to Pylons and my Python skills aren't super strong, so I may be missing something really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Comment: Much thanks. It works.  I'd actually looked at that a few times but couldn't tell if thats what I should be using.  This line was the kicker: site.addsitedir('/usr/local/pythonenv/PYLONS-1/lib/python2.5/site-packages')